# android.net vs java.net and the different URI classes

Tags: android

I'm writing an application with a model object that will expose a Restful interface to some web services. I've noticed that in Android there is a java.net.URI and an android.net.URI class. What are the benefits to using one versus the other? Has anyone else run into this and found that one works better than the other?

In the below code I'm parsing the individual parts of the URI into a java.net URI object so I can then call `httpGet(URI uri)`. However, would there be any performance benefits or any benefits at all to using the android.net classes or just calling httpGet(String url)?

```
public class RestMethods {
    private String protocol;
    private String host;
    private Integer port;
    private URI uri;

    public String restGet(String path) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return "Client Protocol Exception Exception " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "IO Exception " + e.toString();
        }   
        return builder.toString();
    }
...
//Other rest methods, Getters, and setters down here
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there will be performance benefits. The android team doesn't have to conform to the same backwards compatibility restrictions when coding the `android.net` package that they do when they're implementing the `java.net` package. Therefore they can make better optimizations.