# Convert java.net.URI to android.net.Uri

Tags: android, uri

I am able to find how to convert android.net.Uri to Java.net.URI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559902/android-how-can-i-convert-android-net-uri-object-to-java-net-uri-object) but not vice-versa.

So after spending some time I figured it out. Here is the solution(If there is another solution then please post that as well)

First convert javaURI to string and then use android.net.Uri's parse function

```
android.net.URI androidUri = android.net.Uri.parse(javaURI.toString());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.net vs java.net and the different URI classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971275/android-net-vs-java-net-and-the-different-uri-classes)

Answer (score 33):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)

```
public static Uri parse (String uriString)
```

> Creates a Uri which parses the given encoded URI string.
>
> Parameters
>   uriString: an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI
>
> Returns
>   Uri for this given uri string
>
> Throws
>   NullPointerException if uriString is null

---

Therefore, here is an example:

```
android.net.Uri.parse(new java.net.URI("").toString());
```

*Goes without saying, use the real* `java.net.URI` *in it...* **;)**

Comment: This also means you can run Unit Tests on the local JVM without worrying about the Android SDK being present therefore making life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this, I had success with the following code:

```
URI oldUri;
Uri newUri  = new Uri.Builder().scheme(oldUri.getScheme())
                    .encodedAuthority(oldUri.getRawAuthority())
                    .encodedPath(oldUri.getRawPath())
                    .query(oldUri.getRawQuery())
                    .fragment(oldUri.getRawFragment())
                    .build();
```

Basically, get each URI component and pass it to the builder (as there does not seem to be a way to pass in a whole URI string.

Comment: 310 characters vs 43 characters... - `Uri newUri  = Uri.parse(oldUri.toString());` - hmm...

Comment: Just brilliant @saleemrashid1

Comment: Why in the name of god would you do something like that?

Comment: Downvoted because android.net.Uri already have a parse method

Comment: Thank you for this solution. You may want to add a line to handle URIs that contain port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
uri = Uri.parse(mFile.toString());
```