# Whats the difference between Java.Net.Uri and Android.Net.Uri

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uri

I am trying to get a `Uri` from a `file` object like so:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt");
var androidUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString();
var javaUri = file.ToURI().ToString();
```

this returns the following values:

```
androidUri = "file:///sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt"
javaUri = "file:/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt"
```

so my question is whats the difference between the `Java.Net.Uri` and `Android.Net.Uri` are these two values supposed to be different? When should they be used?

**Update**

I found the two documentation pages [Java.Net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) and [Android.Net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) and both say:

> Builds and parses URI references which conform to [RFC 2396](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html).

Therefore surely this is a bug and they should return the same string?

Comment: for android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: similar question and answer here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649530/convert-java-net-uri-to-android-net-uri

Comment: @mayyo I don't see how that question is related? It talks about converting between the two not what the difference is / When they should be used

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difference is that `Android.Net.Uri` is Google's own implementation of RFC 2396.

`Android.Net.Uri` is immutable, hence it is thread-safe. Their implementation is also, according to the [comments in the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/net/Uri.java/), more forgiving. So while `Java.Net.Uri` would throw an `Exception` you attempt to use a garbage Uri, the Android implementation would just return you a Uri with that garbage.

As far as I can tell, `Android.Net.Uri` will only throw NullPointerException and seemingly no other exceptions. While the `Java.Net.Uri` implementation will throw other exceptions such as `URISyntaxException` and `IllegalArgumentException`

Otherwise they seem very similar.

The Uri you get `file:/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt` is valid, and when throwing it through `java.net.URI` I get following:

```
java> String uri = "file:/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt";
java> import java.net.*
java> URI urr = new URI(uri);
java.net.URI urr = file:/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt
java> urr.getScheme();
java.lang.String res2 = "file"
java> urr.getPath();
java.lang.String res3 = "/sdcard/MyFolder/MyFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is one practical difference:

java.net.uri supports IPv4 and IPv6 addresses whereas [android.net.uri only support IPv4](https://ctrl.blog/entry/android-uri-ipv6).

Answer (score 0):

Another difference:

- `android.net.Uri` has [`getQueryParameter(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)) (and a few related methods) to get separate query parameters.
- `java.net.URI` only has [`getRawQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#getRawQuery()) and [`getQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#getQuery()). These methods return the whole query string, e.g. `foo=1&bar=2`.

So if you need to access separate query parameters, `android.net.Uri` may be more convenient.