# Convert from URI to Uri and the other way around

Tags: android, uri, android-file

what's the best way to convert an Uri (android) object to a URI (java.net) object and vice versa? 
I'm converting Uri to URI by using:

```
Uri androidUri;
URI netURI= new URI(androidUri.toString());
```

but I don't know if that's the best way to do it and I don't know how to reverse it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649530/convert-java-net-uri-to-android-net-uri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Converting a URI instance to Uri

**Option 1:**

```
URI androidUri;
Uri newUri = Uri.parse(androidUri.toString());
```

**Option 2**

```
URI androidUri;
Uri newUri  = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(androidUri.getScheme())
    .encodedAuthority(androidUri.getRawAuthority())
    .encodedPath(androidUri.getRawPath())
    .query(androidUri.getRawQuery())
    .fragment(androidUri.getRawFragment())
    .build();
```