# Why does Android have its own URI implementation and doesn't use the default Java implementation?

Tags: java, android, uri

While working with Android applications, I've often run into converting between Android's `Uri` class and Java's `URI` class?

I haven't understood why Android needed its own implementation and didn't use the default `URI` class that ships with Java?

Maybe I have only been scratching the surface when working with URIs and haven't figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971275/android-net-vs-java-net-and-the-different-uri-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Javadoc says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

> In the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.

That is definitely different from the JDK one. Maybe that's why?